# Make Bold any word which starts with @

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I would like to style any word which starts with an "@" character to 'bold' font; for example replacing the string:

> '@xyzharris has a cat @zynPeter'

with:

> '**@xyzHarris** has a cat **@zynPeter**'

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: javascript and jQuery

Answer (score 2):

1. If your target elements **doesn't contain any child element** (*simpler variant*):

```js
$("p:contains(@)").html(function(i, h){
 return h.replace(/(@\w+)/g, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

```css
b{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>@xyzharris has a cat @zynPeter</p>
<p>This is @roko answer to @user21.</p>
<p>@cats like @dogs. A lot.</p>
```

Just make sure you have pure strings inside your `p` selectors. Otherwise,

2. if your target elements **contain inner child elements**:

```js
$('p, p *').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text(function(i, t) {
  $(this).replaceWith(t.replace(/(@\w+)/g, '<b>$1</b>'));
});
```

```css
b{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="#">@xyzharris has a</a> cat @zynPeter</p>
<p>This is <span>@roko answer</span> to @user21.</p>
<p>@cats <i>like @dogs</i>. <span>A lot</span>.</p>
```

In the regex above you see I use `\w` which stands for

> `\w` Matches any letter, number or underscore.

which seems quite cool for a **@us3rn4_me**. If instead you want to  make sure to match any characters but a whitespace than use:

> `\S` Matches anything other than a space, tab or newline.

The `+` Quantifier makes sure to repeat the previous `\w` expression

> `+` one to unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]